# exception while running pre-existing Audit report in JasperReports Server

Tags: java, jasper-reports, weblogic, jasperserver

I am getting below exception while running any of the pre-existing Audit report in *JasperReports Server*.

I have integrated *JR Server* in my *WebLogic*.

Can anybody let me know if I missed any configuration.

The exception is:

```
avax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/jdbc/jasperserver 
in /app/webapp/jasperserver-pro/396844516.; 
remaining name 'comp/env/jdbc/jasperserver' 
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tomcat6 you have a context.xml file with content like this:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/jasperserver" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
    username="postgres" password="12345"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jrs47_repo"  />
```

Then that gets looked up as "java:comp/env/jdbc/jasperserver" to access the repository and to access that audit report.

I don't know WebLogic well. The fact that you are able to use JRS means that you are connecting correctly to the repository. It seems that somewhere you need to indicate that the audit domain needs to use correct JNDI name for the already functioning repository connection.